# Confusion with definition of measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

This is the definition that is confusing me.

> Let $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ be measurable spaces.
>
> A map $f:X \to Y$ is called a measurable function if $f^{-1}(b) \in A \ \ \forall \ \ b \in B$

I do not understand why would $f^{-1}(b)$  be even defined for all $b \in B$. If it is not defined for some $b \in B$, then $f^{-1}(b)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is a slightly sloppy notation that is commonly used: we use the same notation for the image of the inverse of a function (which is not always defined) as for the preimage of a function (which is always defined). Thankfully these coincide when they both make sense, justifying the use of this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ f^{-1}(b) = \left\{ x\in X : f(x) \in b \right\}, $$
where $b$ is some measurable set from the $\sigma$-algebra $B$.  In this case, $f^{-1}$ is *not* the inverse function (indeed, an inverse function may not even exist, which might be the cause of your confusion).  In English, we are saying that $f$ is an $(A,B)$-measurable function if the preimage of each measurable set is measurable.

The preimage *always* makes sense, though it can be empty.  For example, if $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x) = x^2$, then
$$ f^{-1}([-2,-1]) = \emptyset. $$

Comment: Okay, so it makes sense because if there is an element of B which is not mapped by any element A, then it is equivalent to saying that this element is mapped to the null set (no set) ?

Comment: An element $b$ of $B$ is a *set*.  It is possible that no element of $x$ is mapped to $b$, i.e. that $f(x) \not\in b$ for all $x\in X$.  In such a case, $f^{-1}(b)$ is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $(X,A)$ is called a *measurable space* if $X$ is a set and $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$.
This means that the sets $A$ and $B$ are collections of subsets of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Thus $b\in B$ is a subset of $Y$, so $f^{-1}(b)$ is defined because the preimage of a subset of the codomain of a function is always defined.